# Editing Values in the List of Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in python. The Dictionary contains "sequenceId" that I need to update for all Dictionaries making sure that each sequenceId is even and non-repeatable.
To update the sequenceIds, I am using a for loop, but the behavior is not what I expect.

```
seqId = 0
for index in range(20):
    FinalNodes[index]['sequenceId'] = seqId
    seqId +=2

print(FinalNodes[7]['sequenceId'])
```

**Expected Output:-** 14

**Observed Output:-** 38

Here is the full code snipet

```
import json
import time

with open('test.json', "r") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

numberofJobs = 10

NodesList = data['nodes']
nNodes = len(NodesList)
#Divide all node into first, main and last
MainNodes = NodesList[1:nNodes-1]
FirstNode = NodesList[0:1]
LastNode  = NodesList[nNodes-1:nNodes] 

#prepare final nodes
FinalNodes = FirstNode.copy()
for i in range(numberofJobs):
    FinalNodes.extend(MainNodes)
FinalNodes.extend(LastNode)

print(FinalNodes[7]['sequenceId'])

seqId = 0
for index in range(0,20):
    FinalNodes[index]['sequenceId'] = seqId
    seqId +=2
    print(FinalNodes[index]['sequenceId'],index)


print(FinalNodes[7]['sequenceId'])
```

Output Inside the Loop:-

```
0 0
2 1
4 2
6 3
8 4
10 5
12 6
14 7
16 8
18 9
20 10
22 11
24 12
26 13
28 14
30 15
32 16
34 17
36 18
38 19
```

Comment: I think what's happening is that all the dictionaries in your `FinalNodes` are referencing to the same object, so basically you are updating the same dictionary over and over again, resulting in the value to be 38. Can you show us how are you constructing the `FinalNodes`?

Comment: When I ran your code with FinalNodes[index] as a list, it gave the correct result. However, the issue seems to be that the field you have (FieldNodes) is storing the object seqId instead of its value, hence why all indexes of it are returning 38 (which should be the final output of the last field in this loop)

Comment: print the whole of `FinalNodes`: that should tell you what's happening.   Also check e.g. `FinalNodes[0] is FinalNodes[1]`.  (This for general debugging help when this kind of thing happens, although if you post the generation code it should be possible to tell from inspection if the dicts are the same object)

Comment: I have added the complete code snippet. When I print the whole FinalNodes I see different values but still not the expected values. @TYZ

Answer (score -1):

Please check with your `FinalNodes` dictionary as I ran the same code and it works fine!

```
FinalNodes= []
for i in range(20):
    FinalNodes.append({"sequenceId":0})
seqId = 0
for index in range(8):
    FinalNodes[index]['sequenceId'] = seqId
    seqId +=2

print(FinalNodes[7]['sequenceId']) #14
```

Comment: If you are running the loop to "8" you will get 14. Try running it till 20

Comment: Even if u run the code for 20 iterations it gives you 14 as the result.